# How to add authentication on top of Expo Router V2 template

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I created a new React Native project using Expo Router using the following instructions:
https://docs.expo.dev/routing/installation/#quick-start

This is what the app directory looks like:
[image]

The root is a stack navigator, and "(tabs)" is a tab navigator

I want to add authentication to this project. How do I do that?

Previously, I would do something like this:

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const { isContextInitialized } = useDataProvider()!

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {
        isContextInitialized ?  <RootNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

But this will is not working Expo router because it's always rendering whatever file is named index. And if I start changing the names of the files, it behaved very weirdly and continues to try to render some other file.

**Could you please best practices when adding authenticated routes to the starter project for Expo Router?**

Additionally, I have seen these instructions
https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/authentication/

Byt I'm confused on how to set this up with the existing directory structure. Because the existing structure already has a stack-navigator in the root, so I can't use slot to tell the router where to go without adjusting the entire directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I find the Expo [authentication docs](https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/authentication/) do a good job of summarizing the authentication flow.

You can layer routes using folder structures, so by adding an outer folder that requires auth, you don't need logic to toggle between navigators.

Your folder structure will change to:

- app - [new outer directory that's always accessible]

  - _layout.js
  - sign-in.js
  - (app) [Previously your app directory, this contains everything you currently have in app]

    - _layout.js [Use Auth navigator here to protect child routes]
    - index.js [Require authorization]